# Behavior of deadlocking in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm understanding deadlock and trying to create it but instead the code executes successfully. can someone help me understand what excatly is going on.

```
private static Object forLock1=new Object();
    private static Object forLock2=new Object();
    
    
    public static void main(String k[]){
        Thread t1,t2=null;
        
           t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                   synchronized(forLock1){     //Acquires lock on forLock1 and waiting for forLock2
                        synchronized(forLock2){
                            
                   for(int x=0;x<1000;x++)
                   System.out.println("Hello From t1 "+x);
               }}
           };
        }); 
            
      
               t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                   public void run(){
                       synchronized(forLock2){     //Acquires Lock on forLock2 will be waiting for forLock1
                           synchronized(forLock1){
                       for(int x=0;x<1000;x++)
                       System.out.println("Hello from t2 "+x);
                   }}
               };
           });
       
            
           t1.start();  // Both the threads started at same time
           t2.start();
        }
    }
```

As forLock1 is acquired by t1 and forLock2 by t2 both will be mutually waiting for eachother to release the locks resulting in a deadlock but it executes with the output. Why is it so ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html

Comment: The main methods starts the threads one after the other. Chances are very high that the first thread has acquired both locks before the second thread starts running.

Comment: @ThomasKläger- Thank you but what determines the chance of acquiring locks is high for thread 1 before thread 2.

Comment: Since the code obtains the second lock right after first lock, there is only a gap of maybe microseconds between the locks, so the chance that another thread get in-between is extremely small. Since thread 1 is started before thread 2, it is highly likely that thread 1 wins the race for obtaining the locks. Try adding a `Thread.sleep(100)` between the `synchronized` statements, and the probability of causing a deadlock becomes highly likely.

Comment: Your comment says, "Both the threads started at the same time," but in reality, your code first starts the two threads one after the other. They are started _close_ to the same time,... for some definition of "close." But, what seems "close" on one time scale (e.g., seconds) might seem very far from close on another time scale (e.g., microseconds.) As @Andreas said, the window of opportunity for your code to deadlock is at most a few microseconds.